# Question about ". |" notation

Tags: notation

I am confused about the following notation: $r_t \sim R( . | s_t, a_t)$ I know that $r_t$ is equal to $R( . | s_t, a_t)$, however I am unsure what the $. | s_t$ notation means

Comment: In what context did you find this notation?

Comment: I found this in the context of reinforcement learning. More specifically from this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvoHnicueoE, at 8:20.

Comment: Hmm, the best I can guess is that $R$ would then be a function with three arguments, and in order to refer to it as a function of the first argument only, with the second and third fixed, we would write down a dot instead of the first argument (which is pretty common), and then separate it from the two others with a bar (which is not really common). I may be completely mistaken, but I would interpret it like this...